# Pyspark df.write taking extremely long (over 24 hours)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, databricks

I am writing data from databricks to GCP (a pyspark df of just over 8,000,000 rows and 3 columns)

```
df\
    .write\
    .format("bigquery")\
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "databricks-bq-342")\
    .option("table", "database1:merch.table1")\
    .mode("overwrite")\
    .save()
```

The command is stuck now for over a day and the current job isn't completing. Could this be an issue with the cluster (as just running display(df) is taking 10 mins).

What's the solution?

I have tried the above to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell the exact problem with just this general information, but I would try visiting the Spark UI for the cluster and seeing if there are some straggler tasks/partitions that are taking way too long, perhaps due to uneven data distribution or due to things like DB throttling.